# Write to a single log file in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, singleton

I have written a small sub to create log file

```
sub WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, sLogFileLine) 
    logfolder = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\Logfolder\"
    ScriptName1 = Replace(Wscript.ScriptName, ".vbs", "")
    sLogFileName = ScriptName1 & "_" & date & "_" & hour(now) & "-" & minute(now) & "-" & second(now) & "_log.txt"
    sLogFileNameFull = logfolder & sLogFileName
    dateStamp = Now()
    Set MyLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileNameFull, 8, True)
    MyLog.WriteLine(cstr(dateStamp) + vbTab + "-" + vbTab + sLogFileLine) 
    MyLog.Close
    Set MyLog = Nothing 
end sub
```

I am calling this sub multiple times in my main vb script function to write messages to the log file this way,

```
'******************************************************************************
'* Main Script Body
'******************************************************************************
Function DoAllWork
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sFile, FromDate, ToDate, FromLocation, MyFile, objFolder, Filename, objArgs, FilenameReq, line, inFile, outFile, outputLines
    Dim FromdateFile, FromdateFileReq, lineDt, CFileDt, CopyFiles, line1, CFile, resultX, stringY, resultY, resultfinal, outputLine
    Dim FromFolderList, ToLocationArg, outputLines1, Arch, ToLocationArg1, writeOutput
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments 
    Set MyLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileNameFull, 8, True)

    If WScript.Arguments.Count = 4 Then 
        Call WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, "Total number of arguments passed are " & WScript.Arguments.Count & " and they are as follows : ")
        'Parameter1, begin with index0
        FromDate = WScript.Arguments(0)
        'Parameter2
        ToDate = WScript.Arguments(1)
        'Parameter3
        FromLocationArg = WScript.Arguments(2)
        'Parameter4
        ToLocation = WScript.Arguments(3)
    Else 
        Call WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, "Error, Must pass 4 arguments to the script !" & vbcrlf)
        Wscript.quit 
    End if 
    Call WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, "First Argument, the date folder FROM where files needs to be copied is : " & FromDate & vbcrlf)
    Call WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, "Second Argument, the date folder TILL where files needs to be copied is : " & ToDate & vbcrlf)
MyLog.Close
    Set MyLog = Nothing 

    DoAllWork = Err.Number
    Call WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, "End of the script !" & vbcrlf)
End Function

'******************************************************************************
'* End of the script.
'******************************************************************************
```

But while executing the script sometimes there are multiple log files getting generated, I guess everytime the timestamp is changing it is creating a new log file and writting log in that file.

QUE : I want all the log to be written to one single log file whose timestamp is picked up at the beginning of my script. Please help !!

Comment: You're not storing the filename and creating it dynamically to the second so if `OpenTextFile()` doesn't find it because you pass `True` it will create it each time.

Comment: @lankymart - I tried to create the file only once in my main function and tried to pass that as an argument everytime to my sub but then no log file is getting created in that case.

Comment: Can you show that code? The way you have at the moment it will create a new file every second.

Comment: @Lankymart - I have updated my question with the main function where I am calling this sub. The sub is written before the function in my script.

Comment: Where is `sLogFileNameFull` set? Is it declared globally?

Comment: The first four lines of `WriteLogFileLine()` should be inside the `DoAllwork()` function so the name is generated before `WritelogFileline()` is called.

Comment: @Lankymart - Hey I tried the way u said and it worked now !! Thanks for ur help. I had tried similar things earlier but it was not working earlier. Not sure what I was doing wrong. Thanks again !!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logging function has an argument for the full path to the log file, so you should define the filename once at the beginning of your code and use that name throughout the entire script (I'd recommend doing the same for the `FileSystemObject` instance). Remove all code defining the filename from the logging function.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

logfolder    = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\Logfolder"
ScriptName1  = Replace(Wscript.ScriptName, ".vbs", "")
sLogFileName = ScriptName1 & "_" & Date & "_" & Hour(Now) & "-" & _
               Minute(Now) & "-" & Second(Now) & "_log.txt"
logfile = objFSO.BuildPath(logfolder, sLogFileName)

Sub WriteLogFileLine(sLogFileNameFull, sLogFileLine)
    Set MyLog = objFSO.OpenTextFile(sLogFileNameFull, 8, True)
    MyLog.WriteLine Now & vbTab & "-" & vbTab & sLogFileLine
    MyLog.Close
End Sub

...
WriteLogFileLine logfile, "some log line"
...
```

You may want to take a look at the [logger class](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/clogger.shtml) I wrote a couple years ago (if you'll forgive the shameless plug). It might help simplify your log handling. Copy the class code into your script and you can do logging like this:

```
logfolder = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\Logfolder"
logname   = Replace(Wscript.ScriptName, ".vbs", "") & "_" & Date & "_" & _
            Hour(Now) & "-" & Minute(Now) & "-" & Second(Now) & "_log.txt"
logfile   = objFSO.BuildPath(logfolder, logname)

Set clog = New CLogger
clog.LogToConsole = False
clog.LogFile = logfile      'open log
clog.IncludeTimestamp = True

...
clog.LogInfo "some message"
clog.LogError "other message"
...

clog.LogFile = ""           'close log
```

The log file is closed automatically when the script terminates (if it wasn't already closed in the code before).

Comment: Thanks @ansgar wiechers. I will try this in my script.

Comment: @Pals If you want to use the `Clogger` class you will need to wrap your `.vbs` script and the `clogger.vbs` inside a `.wsf` *(Windows Script File)* file before it will work. See [Using Windows Script Files (.wsf)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/15x4407c(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: Simply copying the class code into the script would suffice. Using the import procedure mentioned in my blog post is another option.

Comment: Then what's the point in having it in a class? WSFs work and make it simple to incorporate modular code. Even your import function requires having the code in the source vbs file, how else is it going to add it?

Comment: @Lankymart Encapsulation and automatic cleanup are the main reasons for using a class. Using .wsf files is one way of including the class code, but it's not the only one.

Comment: I know what the benefits of using a class. I was speaking in terms of your suggested methods, *"copying class code"* and *"using the import procedure"*.

Comment: @Lankymart I pointed out alternatives, since your comment made it sound like .wsf files were the only way. That's all.

Comment: @  Ansgar Wiechers, I have used the above logfile creation method in my script. But now when the logfile size becomes too big, it becomes unreadable. I am trying to implement the below method from  Lankymart where we check if the logfile size is bigger than a specified value and if yes then we just try to create a new logfile and start writing to it. Now in this case as we have the timestamp in the logfile name and as it is being passed in the main script, I am not able to implement the below function in my script. Can u please help ?

Comment: @Pals Please do not move the target. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I created this to do what you have asked. I use it to keep logs as the scripts run via a scheduled task.

```
Dim FSO, OutPutFile
Dim DateTimeString
Dim LogDirectory, LogFileName, MaxLogFileSize

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'The Log File Directory
LogDirectory = "E:\LogFiles"

'The name of the log file for this script
LogFileName = "archive.log"

'The maximun Log file Size in Megabytes
MaxLogFileSize = 5

SetUpLogFile()

DateTimeString = GetCurrentDateTimeString
OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " " + "----------------------------------")
DateTimeString = GetCurrentDateTimeString
OutPutFile.WriteLine(DateTimeString + " " + "Writing to the log file.")

'=============================================================
Function SetUpLogFile()

'First Thing: Check if log file exists, and if it exceeds max Size
If (FSO.FileExists(LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName)) Then

    Dim CurrentLogFile, CurrentLogFileSize
    Set CurrentLogFile = FSO.GetFile(LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName)
    CurrentLogFileSize = CurrentLogFile.Size

    'Convert Size to MB
    CurrentLogFileSize = ((CurrentLogFileSize \ 1024) \ 1024)

    'Check if log file exceeds maximum size
    If (CurrentLogFileSize >= MaxLogFileSize) Then

        'Get a unique string to re-name backup log with
        Dim LogDateTimeString
        LogDateTimeString = cstr(Year(date)) + "_" + _
        + cstr(Month(date)) + "_" _
        + cstr(Day(date)) + "__" _
        + cstr(Hour(time)) + "_" _
        + cstr(Minute(time)) + "_" _
        + cstr(Second(time))

        'rename old log file
        CurrentLogFile.Name = LogDateTimeString + "_" + CurrentLogFile.Name
        'create new log file
        Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName ,8 , True)

    Else
        'Just append to the log file if it is not over the max size
        Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName ,8 , True)

    End If

Else
    'Create Log File if it does not yet exist
    Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName ,8 , True)

End If

'Output to a window if the log file cannot be used
'All errors for any other condition will get logged to the
'log file
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

   wscript.echo "ERROR: Error creating or writing to log file: " + _
      LogDirectory + "\" + LogFileName + vbcrlf + _
      "Please fix the problem as the script will now quit and cannot continue." +  _
      vbcrlf + vbcrlf + _
      "Error information:" + vbcrlf + _
      "Error Number: " + cstr(Err.Number) + vbcrlf + _
      "Source: " +  Err.Source + vbcrlf + _
      "Description: " +  Err.Description

    wscript.quit

End If

End Function

'=============================================================

Function GetCurrentDateTimeString()

'Build Date Time String For Logging
Dim tmp, ReturnDateString

tmp = Right("00" & Month(Now()), 2)
ReturnDateString = ReturnDateString + tmp + "/"

tmp = Right("00" & Day(Now()), 2)
ReturnDateString = ReturnDateString + tmp + "/" + cstr(Year(date)) + " "

tmp = Right("00" & Hour(Now()), 2)
ReturnDateString = ReturnDateString + tmp + ":"

tmp = Right("00" & Minute(Now()), 2)
ReturnDateString = ReturnDateString + tmp + ":"

tmp = Right("00" & Second(Now()), 2)
ReturnDateString = ReturnDateString + tmp + " -"

GetCurrentDateTimeString = ReturnDateString

End Function
'=============================================================
```

Comment: I've got a shortcut for the `AddZeroToDateValue()` function that will save you lines of unnecessary code and I kicked myself when I discovered it. `Right("00" & value, 2)` so simple!

Comment: @Lankymart I had to take off the () characters to get it to compile, but it does not appear to work if I replace my code with your suggestion in the AddZeroToDateValue() function.

Comment: You can't just replace your code with mine that was just showing the method for padding zeros without needing a bloated `AddZeroToDateValue()` function. You would just use it like `tmp = Right("00" & Hour(Time()), 2)` for example to pad the Hours. As for the `()` comment I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Lankymart I got the error 'Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub'. So you are saying I should ditch the AddZeroToDateValue() function and implement your call in GetCurrentDateTimeString()?

Comment: @Lankymart Really weird thing I experienced trying to use your suggestion. This line returns the value '30'. tmp = Right("00" & Day(Time()), 2). Where as this line returns '07' correctly. tmp = Right("00" & Day(date), 2). At least for today's date.

Comment: That's not weird, how do you expect to return `Day()` by passing in the current `Time()`? Personally I always use `Now()` as it contains both `Date()` and `Time()` so works for both.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks. Good suggestion. I revised my answer with your suggestion.