# Nice Label Automation builder Triggers and VBScript

Tags: vbscript

We are using NiceLabel Automation Builder – Easy

We have a trigger that opens a label, sets the printer (via a variable), prints the label and then executes a vbscript as shown below.

The main issue, is using the label variable `[POC.ID]`, when we try to assign it to `adpar1Value` we get the following error.

> Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation
>   in the line of code below.

```
set par1 =adoCmd.CreateParameter (adPar1Name, adPar1Type, adPar1Direction,4,adpar1Value)
```

However, if we hardcode a value to adpar1Value eg. `adpar1Value = “48”` and execute the script, it works as intended.

Can anyone suggest the error in the line of code?

Can anyone suggest error trapping within NiceLabel Automation Builder process?

We are uncertain if `[POC.ID]` retains its value in the vbscript after the label has been printed.

```
'Function to query database and return xml string
    Dim Part                             '    as StockCode Filter
    Dim adoCmd         '      As ADODB.Command
    Dim adoConn        '      As ADODB.adoConnection 
    Dim outStrm        '        As ADODB.Stream
    Dim txtResults     '        String for results
    Dim ConString       '     String for adoConnection
    Dim sQuery         '         Query String
    Dim fso            '              File System Object
    Dim ts             '               Text Stream
    Dim dbName         '      The DNS name or IP address of your DB Server
    Dim Catalog        '              The specific database to adoConnect to
    Dim TableName      '    The table we will retrieve data from
    Dim UID            ' The User Name to login to your database (Not used)
    Dim PWD            '          The Password to login to your database (Not used)


'Connect to the database
'*******************************************************

                Catalog  = "DataWarehouse_XXXX"
'Set our server name
                dbName = "OUR-SERVER"
                ConString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" _
                           & "Initial Catalog=" & Catalog & ";Data Source=" & dbName & ";"
'msgbox (sadoConn)
                Set adoConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                adoConn.ConnectionString = ConString
               ' adoConn.CursorLocation =  3
                adoConn.Open


'Execute a stored procedure
'********************************************
'Create SQL Command Object

Set adoCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
adoCmd.commandtype = 4 'To run store procedure
adoCmd.commandtext = "CHC_Labels.usp_UpdatePrinterStatus" 'stored procedure name

'Create Parameter object
dim par1, adpar1Value
Const adPar1Name="@ID"
Const adPar1Type=200 'For string see microsoft docs DataTypeEnum
Const adPar1Direction = 1 'For input see microsoft for ParameterDirectionEnum
'Const adPar1Size = 200 ' specifies the maximum length for the parameter value in characters or bytes.

adpar1Value = [POC.ID]

' Format Set parameter = command.CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)  
set par1 =adoCmd.CreateParameter (adPar1Name,adPar1Type, adPar1Direction,4,adpar1Value)

'Add the parameter to the Command object
adoCmd.Parameters.Append par1


adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoConn
adoCmd.Execute 



'Cleanup Database objects
'*******************************************************

     adoConn.Close

     set adoConn = Nothing

     set adoCmd = Nothing

     set outStrm = Nothing
```

Comment: Have you tried writing things (eg, variables) to a log file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132848/write-to-a-single-log-file-in-vbscript

Comment: No but good call thanks